I don't uderstand why the Lagrange multipliers don't work here $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y-z$ with constraint $x^2-y^2+z=0$
When calculating the above lagrange multipliers you will find that the system has one solution where the point that solves it is $C (0,-1/2,1/4)$ which is $f(C)=1/4$. But if you calculate $f(0,0,0)=0$ which less than $1/4$ and if you calculate $f(4,4,0)=12$ which is more than $1/4$. So how can I actually find the min max of the function and why the Lagrange multiplier method does not work for calculating the minimum and maximum.
Is the problem that I haven't calculated what the determinant is at that point to find if there is a minimum or a maximum to this function?

The set $\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2-y^2+z\right\}$ is an unbounded set (for instance, it contains all points of the line $\{(x,-x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, and therefore the method of Lagrange multipliers can only give you local extreme points. But there is no global maximum ($\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,-x,0)=\infty$) and there is no global minimum ($\lim_{x\to\infty}f(0,x,x^2)=-\infty$).

So is there a more general way to know before using the lagrange method if it will help me find the extremes of a function with a constraint?

No, but you can classify the local extrema you find using just derivative information of the objective and constraint https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian

The question has been answered.
Perhaps instructive to rewrite $f(x,y,z)$ with the given constraint.
Constraint: $z=-x^2+y^2$
Substituting for $z:$
$F(x, y)= 2x^2-y^2-y;$
$F(x, y) =$
$2x^2 - (y+1/2)^2+1/4;$
Note that $2x^2\ge 0$ and
$-(y+1/2)^2 \le 0$.
You found a critical point at $C(0,-1/2,1/4).$
By looking at $f(x, y, z)$ (simplified) can you tell if it is a local max or min?
Does any other point qualify?
